# How to convert an excel sheet in to a specific format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, windows

How to specify 6 columns and name them in datagridview so that when I import an excel sheet with missing columns it adds the missing columns. I need to keep the content empty and arrange the columns based on what I specify in datagridview. Note: column name does not change.

For example, I specify columns A,B,C,D in datagridview and the excel sheet has the same column names, but some of them are missing, for example (A,C)

This is what I did to import excel sheet into the application:

```
namespace excelreaderdesktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fil = new OpenFileDialog();
            fil.ShowDialog();
            string path = fil.FileName.ToString();
            ExcelFileReader(path);
        }

        public void ExcelFileReader(string path)
        {
            var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
            var result = reader.AsDataSet();
            var tables = result.Tables.Cast<DataTable>();
            foreach(DataTable table in tables)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverfow,

if I have understand your question correct, look wich columns are exist in the *dataGridView1* and check them against the excel file in the excel-file.

Example:

```
// create an exapmle DataTabel (in your case your tables from the excel-file)
// The excel-file has the columns B and D
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("B");
table.Columns.Add("D");

// loop over the columns in the dataGridView1
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    // xheck whether the column exists in the table, otherwise add it. 
    if (!table.Columns.Contains(column.Name))
    {
        table.Columns.Add(column.Name);
    }
}

// clear old columns from dataGridView1
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

// update dataGridView1
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Hoppefully this helps you.

Comment: hi Kamukiesel thanks for the reply I don't believe you have got my point the situation is for example i want to configure the datagrideview1 to have 6 columns with A,B,C,D,E,F that are fixed. with a click of a button i want to import excel file that has  some missing columns like for example A,B,C,D only. how to add the missing columns

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. Understand I your comment correct that in the excle-file are the columns E and F, but not A,B,C and D.